# Facebook - FB.ui - Like Method Name?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What is the facebook like method name as add bookmark method 'bookmark.add'

```
FB.ui( {method: 'bookmark.add' },
function(response) {
 //Handle Response
        }
     );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method for adding a like. Liking something through any facebook api is not supported. The only way you can have a user like something is by using the official like buttons.

Comment: I am developing Flash Application and need to display like status and set like option inside flash. Is there any other way that I can set like from flash.

Comment: Not directly. You will have to display the html iframe version somehow. This is hopefully something that they will solve eventually since this is a common complaint, but for now there really isnt a good solution. Also, don't forget to mark this as the answer. :)